# Double quotes:syntax error near the `token 'not expected' ('

Tags: bash, echo

I want to use double quotes (`""`) inside of echo command like this example below:

```
echo "  
 ^%(log_prefix)s SecurityEvent=(FailedACL|InvalidAccountID|ChallengeResponseFailed|InvalidPassword)",EventTV="[\d-]+",Severity="[\w]+",Service="[\w]+",EventVersion="\d+",AccountID="\d+",SessionID="0x[\da-f]+",LocalAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/[\da-fA-F:.]+/\d+",RemoteAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/<HOST>/\d+"(,Challenge="\w+",ReceivedChallenge="\w+")?(,ReceivedHash="[\da-f]+")?$

 " > /etc/test.conf
```

And I want to put this text inside of '/etc/test.conf'

But, when I type this bash, it returns me an error: `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Since you're not using any variables, use `echo '....'`  - ie single `'` and not `"`

Comment: Spotted this: `>/\d+"(,Cha`

Comment: Can you format your code better, please? (I'll suggest an edit)

Answer (score 4):

There are some shell special characters that will be expanded within double quotes present in your string.

Use single quotes instead given you are expecting any expansion from shell:

```
echo '<your_string>' >/etc/test.conf
```

This will treat the string literally.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want to put empty lines, you can use `cat` instead of `echo`:

```
cat << 'EOT' > /etc/test.conf

 ^%(log_prefix)s SecurityEvent=(FailedACL|InvalidAccountID|ChallengeResponseFailed|InvalidPassword)",EventTV="[\d-]+",Severity="[\w]+",Service="[\w]+",EventVersion="\d+",AccountID="\d+",SessionID="0x[\da-f]+",LocalAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/[\da-fA-F:.]+/\d+",RemoteAddress="IPV[46]/(UD|TC)P/<HOST>/\d+"(,Challenge="\w+",ReceivedChallenge="\w+")?(,ReceivedHash="[\da-f]+")?$

EOT
```

Comment: You'd still need to watch out for backslashes, `$` and `\`` there. Use `cat << 'EOT'` if you don't want any expansion to take place there.